# Quartz.Net Triggers firing more then once at the same time

Tags: c#, iis, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am currently working on an application, where I use the Quartz Scheduler for scheduling jobs to send an email containing some log data.

I currently have 9 triggers on a host server for testing, that start firing at 08:00 and then each hour till  16:00 Mon to Fri.

However I have a problem with my triggers firing more than once.

I've tried a few different things to make it stop, but I just can't seem to make it.

I've tried adding

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
```

Above the Job being called by the scheduls.
I have tried resetting the IIS on the host server, in an attempt of resetting it. Before I published the next version of the code.

But when they are triggered, to be exact. Currently they fire 4 times. After I restarted the IIS. They first fired once, then twice and then they fired four times and stayed at that amount.

The way I have it set up is with a **Start** method in the **JobSchdul** class.

Where I then have the triggers and jobs placed that I need started, on application start.

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var httpRunPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
        var serverMapPath = Server.MapPath(".");

        JobScheduler scheduler = new JobScheduler();
        scheduler.Start(serverMapPath, httpRunPath);
    }
```

Just to note, the reason I have 9 triggers, is for testing purposes. They are running on the host server, while I try and fix the issue on my dev machine.

**JobScheduler.cs**

```
public void Start(string serverPath, string httpPath)
    {

        try
        {
            var toDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7).ToString();
            var to = "clm@thansen.dk";
            var serverMapPath = serverPath;
            var httpRunPath = httpPath;
            var workingDays = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday };

            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail emailerJob = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(8, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // Extra scheduls

            // 1
            IJobDetail emailerJob1 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(9, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 2
            IJobDetail emailerJob2 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job2", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger2", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(10, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 3
            IJobDetail emailerJob3 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job3", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger3 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger3", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(11, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 4
            IJobDetail emailerJob4 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job4", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger4 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger4", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(12, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 5
            IJobDetail emailerJob5 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job5", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger5 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger5", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(13, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 6
            IJobDetail emailerJob6 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job6", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger6 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger6", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(14, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            // 7
            IJobDetail emailerJob7 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job7", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger7 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger7", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(15, 0, workingDays))
                .Build();

            IJobDetail emailerJob8 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job8", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Starts on application start")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger8 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger8", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(15, 30, workingDays))
                .Build();

            IJobDetail emailerJob9 = JobBuilder.Create<BrokenIMGMailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job9", "Information")
                .WithDescription("Extra job test")
                .Build();

            ITrigger emailerTrigger9 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger9", "Information")
                .UsingJobData("toDate", toDate)
                .UsingJobData("fromDate", fromDate)
                .UsingJobData("to", to)
                .UsingJobData("serverMapPath", serverMapPath)
                .UsingJobData("httpRunPath", httpRunPath)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(15, 40, workingDays))
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob, emailerTrigger);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob1, emailerTrigger1);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob2, emailerTrigger2);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob3, emailerTrigger3);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob4, emailerTrigger4);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob5, emailerTrigger5);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob6, emailerTrigger6);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob7, emailerTrigger7);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob8, emailerTrigger8);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailerJob9, emailerTrigger9);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.WriteLog(1, "JobScheduler", "Start", "Start trigger", $"EXCEPTION MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | EXCEPTION INNER: {ex.InnerException}", LogType.Exception, "");
        }
    }
```

**JobClass.cs - Which contains my other job classes aswell**

```
 [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class BrokenIMGMailJob : IJob
{
    LoggingRepository logging = new LoggingRepository();
    Email _email = new Email();

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
            JobDataMap dataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;


            var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataMap.GetString("toDate"));
            var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataMap.GetString("fromDate"));
            var tmpTo = dataMap.GetString("to");
            string[] toArr;
            string to;
            string httpPath;

            // Gets the path for where the site is being run
            var serverMapPath = dataMap.GetString("serverMapPath");
            var httpRunPath = dataMap.GetString("httpRunPath");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverMapPath))
            {
                httpPath = httpRunPath;
            }
            else
            {
                httpPath = serverMapPath;
            }

            // Regex:
            // (?<=/ ).* : Gets the last parts of the line
            //.+?(?= /) : Gets everything from the start of the line till  " / "
            var regex = new Regex(".+?(?= /)|(?<=/ ).*");

            // List for either not found images or bad images
            var notFoundList = new List<string>();
            var badList = new List<string>();

            // 1) Retreive 7 hours worth of Images
            var logs = logging.getDaysErrorLogs(3, fromDate, toDate); // fromDate: DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7) toDate:DateTime.Now

            // 2) Sort their names and take only the image name "xxxx1.jpg/JPG"
            foreach (var log in logs)
            {
                //(ShowImage|ProcessImage| / )
                var matches = regex.Matches(log.ActionName);
                var fileName = matches[1].ToString();

                if (log.Message == "Image not found")
                {
                    notFoundList.Add(fileName);
                }
                if (log.Message == "Bad image")
                {
                    badList.Add(fileName);
                }
            }

            // 3) Count how many of each instance exists
            var notFoundGroup = notFoundList.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
            var badGroup = badList.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
            // 4) Set up mail with the information nicely displayed
            var msg = $"<div style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:small'>";
            msg += $"Current URL: {httpPath}";
            msg += $"<h2>Beskadiget billeder</h2> ";
            msg += $"Antal forekomster: {badList.Count()}<br/>";
            msg += $"Forekomster i tidsrummet <b>{fromDate.ToString("dd MMM HH:mm:ss")}</b> til <b>{toDate.ToString("dd MMM HH:mm:ss")}</b><br/>";
            msg += $"<b>Filnavn - Antal forkomster</b><br/>";
            msg += $"-------------------------------------<br/>";
            foreach (var file in notFoundGroup)
            {
                msg += $"{file.Key} - ({file.Count()})<br/>";
            }
            msg += $"-------------------------------------<br/>";

            msg += $"<br/><h2>Ikke fundet billeder</h2>";
            msg += $"Antal forekomster: {notFoundList.Count()}<br/>";
            msg += $"Forekomster i tidsrummet <b>{fromDate.ToString("dd MMM HH:mm:ss")}</b> til <b>{toDate.ToString("dd MMM HH:mm:ss")}</b><br/>";
            msg += $"<b>Filnavn - Antal forkomster</b><br/>";
            msg += $"-------------------------------------<br/>";
            foreach (var file in badGroup)
            {
                msg += $"{file.Key} - ({file.Count()})<br/>";
            }
            msg += $"-------------------------------------<br/>";
            msg += $"<p>Denne besked blev sent, {DateTime.Now.ToString("U")}</p>";
            msg += $"</div>";

            if (tmpTo.Contains(";"))
            {
                toArr = Regex.Split(tmpTo, ";");
                _email.SendEmail(toArr, "Bad and Not found Images", msg, true);
            }
            else
            {
                to = tmpTo;
                _email.SendEmail(to, "Bad and Not found Images", msg, true);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            logging.WriteLog(1, "JobClass", "BrokenIMGMailJob","Send broken images mail", $"EXCEPTION MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | EXCEPTION INNER: {ex.InnerException}", LogType.Exception, "");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with IIS. This problem has been discussed many times in Stackoverflow. IIS is not the best platform for running long living threads as you have to deal with application pool recycling and memory leaks. Unless you can configure IIS to tackle these problems consider using a Windows service instead.

Comment: @derloopkat Thanks for the notes, my co-worker seemed to agree with you. So now we're looking into what can be done about it.